# How to solve duplication in case statement using sql

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to resolve duplication of my data using case statement as I want all cases about a name source to be in one row,

For example

```
create table sourceTbl (Name varchar(8), Value varchar(8))
GO

INSERT INTO sourceTbl VALUES('David', 'Car');
INSERT INTO sourceTbl VALUES('Mike', ' Bus');
INSERT INTO sourceTbl VALUES('Jerry', 'Train');
INSERT INTO sourceTbl VALUES('David', 'Train');
INSERT INTO sourceTbl VALUES('Sola', 'Bike');
```

My query:

```
select name
    ,case when value ='car'   then 'true' else 'false' end as car
    ,case when value ='Train' then 'true' else 'false' end as train
    ,case when value ='bus'   then 'true' else 'false' end as bus
    ,case when value ='bike'  then 'true' else 'false' end as bike
from sourceTbl
group by name
    ,case when value ='car'   then 'true' else 'false' end
    ,case when value ='Train' then 'true' else 'false' end
    ,case when value ='bus'   then 'true' else 'false' end
    ,case when value ='bike'  then 'true' else 'false' end
```

If you filter the name to get the result for David result come in this manner

```
Name    car     Bus      Train    Bike
David   True    False    False    False
David   False   False    True    False
```

The result I need

```
Name    car     Bus      Train    Bike
David   True    False    True    False
```

How do I run a SQL select to get this result?

Comment: Simply remove the duplicated case condition?

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: As currently stands after editing, this question is answerable and valid by SO rules. Would appreciate another vote to reopen.  Thx.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Reopen queue completed.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select name
    ,MAX(case when value ='car'   then 'true' else 'false' end) as car
    ,MAX(case when value ='Train' then 'true' else 'false' end) as train
    ,MAX(case when value ='bus'   then 'true' else 'false' end) as bus
    ,MAX(case when value ='bike'  then 'true' else 'false' end) as bike
from sourceTbl 
group by name
```

As mentioned in another answer, you should only be grouping on `name` and then use aggregate functions to collapse the other column's values into a single total value for that `name`.  In this case `MAX(..)` works because the string 'true' is greater than the string 'false'.